# TypeError: onVideoSelect is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on simple video player react app, that makes api calls to youtube and lets users select and play the videos in the app. The whole idea was to describe a call back method(onVideoSelect) on the JSX of the VideoList instance in the App component(index.js) and pass it as props to the VideoListItem component where it can be called on clicking on a video list item
Here is code for my index.js file. This file contains the app(parent) component.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';
import VideoDetail from './components/video_detail';

const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyCAfItybV7pSzxmwTj5wyG5SErMs5HYlRQ'

// create a new component. This component should produce some HTML
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      videos: [],
      selectedVideo: null
    };

    YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'internet of things'}, (videos) => {
      this.setState({
        videos:videos,
        selectedVideo: videos[0]
      });
    });

  }
  render() {
    return (<div>
            <SearchBar />
            <VideoDetail video = {this.state.selectedVideo} />
            <VideoList
            onVideoSelect={selectedVideo => this.setState({selectedVideo})}
            videos = {this.state.videos} />
          </div>
        );
  };
}

// Take this component's generated HTML and place it on the page(DOM)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

search_bar.js contains code for the SearchBar component i have not yet wired though.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class SearchBar extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = { term: '' };
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>

        <input
        value = {this.state.term}
        onChange={event => this.setState({ term: event.target.value})} />

      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default SearchBar;
```

video_detail.js file has code for the VideoDetail component

```js
import React from 'react';

const VideoDetail = ({video}) => {

if (!video){
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}
const videoId = video.id.videoId;
const url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`;

  return(
    <div className="video-detail col-md-8">
      <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe className="embed-responsive-item" src={url}></iframe>
      </div>
      <div className="details">
      <div>{video.snippet.title}</div>
      <div>{video.snippet.description}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoDetail;
```

video_list_item.js contains code for the VideoListItem component

```js
import React from 'react';

const VideoListItem = ({video, onVideoSelect}) => {
const imgUrl = video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
  //const video = props.video;
  return (
    <li onClick={() => onVideoSelect(video)} className = "list-group-item">
      <div className ="video-list media">
        <div className ="media-left">
          <img className = "media-object" src = {imgUrl} />
        </div>

        <div className = "media-body">
          <div className = "media-heading">{video.snippet.title}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

export default VideoListItem;
```

video_list.js contains code for the VideoList component as shown below

```js
import React from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';


const VideoList = (props) => {
  const videoItems = props.videos.map((video) => {
    return(
      <VideoListItem
      onVideoSelect = {props.onVideoSelect}
      key = {video.etag}
      video = {video} />
    );
  });

  return(
    <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
    {videoItems}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default VideoList;
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with this code and it should work...

Comment: Yeah, it finally worked I don't know how. I just restarted my development environment.

Comment: It happens.....